# Unable to get Next.js server-side environment variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, environment-variables, runtime

I have the following api-helper that sets the base API URI

```
import getConfig from 'next/config'

  // URI for back end
  const {publicRuntimeConfig} = getConfig()
   
  const apiUri = publicRuntimeConfig.external_uri;

  export {apiUri}
```

This is my next.config.js (removed other code for brevity)

```
module.exports = {

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will be available on both server and client
    external_uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TEST_URI,
  },

};
```

**On my machine**, I've set the environment variable NEXT_PUBLIC_TEST_URI to a value. However, when I look at my API call on the client-side, it is still showing as undefined.

On the other hand, when I populate the environment variables using **the .env files** in my project folder, everything works as expected.

I understand there may be a need to use getServersideProps in my api-helper but I'm not sure how I can do it in a simple way just to initialize a variable. It would also be good to understand why it works with the .env files but not an actual environment variable on the server.

I need it to work with an actual environment variable on the server as my end objective is to be able to update this variable and restart the node service without needing to rebuild the app.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I think next.config only reads from the .env file itself and ignores everything else, which is an issue

Comment: Hi @DrorBar, did you ever manage to find a solution to this?